# Angular checkbox filtering data list

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Seen a few options for filtering data via checkboxes but it all seems fairly overly complicated for something I'd expect Angular to do easily.

Take a nose at http://plnkr.co/edit/Gog4qkLKxeH7x3EnBT0i

So there are a few filters in place here but the ones I'm interested in are the checkboxes. Using a pretty nifty Angular UI module I found called Unique, it lists the different types of providers and rather than repeating them, just lists one of each type. Lovely stuff.

However I can't get that to filter the results set below. However if I take the rendered markup from the generated checkboxes and put that directly into the HTML, it works, even though it is the same. Madness.

I don't understand filtering enough, so what am I doing wrong? I was hoping to use the unique module for a couple of other checkbox filters. Like door numbers, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution; showing diffs only:

In index.html modify the relevant lines as follows:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="result in results | unique: 'provider.name'">
    <input type="checkbox"
        id="cb_{{ result.provider.providerId }}"
        data-ng-model="checkbox[result.provider.providerId]"
    />
    <label for="cb_{{ result.provider.providerId }}">{{ result.provider.name }}</label>
</li>
...
<li data-ng-repeat="result in ( filteredItems = (results | filter: searchByCarClass | filter: selectCarClass | filter: searchByCheckbox )) | orderBy:orderByFilter">
    ...
</li>
```

In script.js add:

```
$scope.checkbox = {};
var showAll = true;
$scope.searchByCheckbox = function(result) {
    return showAll || $scope.checkbox[result.provider.providerId];
};
$scope.$watch("checkbox", function(newval, oldval) {
    showAll = true;
    angular.forEach($scope.checkbox, function(val) {
        if( val === true ) showAll = false;
    });
}, true);
```

(EDIT) Changed the key to `$scope.checkbox` to `providerId`. Filter starts disabled, so all entries are shown.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. On my phone at the moment so can't test/play with this. All results should display at first, without there being a checked checkbox.

Comment: So checking a checkbox *hides* the relevant records (checked means filtered out)? Or when all checkboxes are inactive the filtering is considered inactive too (all unchecked -> no filter, at least one checked -> show only relevant entries)? Either way, it should be simple to implement based on the above.

Comment: It should show all by default, with no checkboxes checked. Then the user can edit the view.

Comment: Hello. Having issues saving to Plunkr but unfortunately your edit does not list all from the start. Will send a link as soon as Plunkr works.

Comment: Punkr updated http://plnkr.co/edit/Gog4qkLKxeH7x3EnBT0i?p=preview

no results showing on load

Comment: Indeed, had forgotten to update the checkbox filter function. Please add `return showAll || ...`. (post edited)

Comment: By the way, Plunkr has troubles executing the plunks from where I am, so I was editing locally, thus the transfer errors :)

Comment: Great, thanks! For what it's worth, I think Angular should do this in a much more simple fashion. For me it's extra logic that seems unnecessary compared to the normal filter.

Comment: Now that you mention it, it may be a good idea to refactor this into a reusable component of some type (service? filter?).

Comment: Reusable? Oh yes please. Chances are there will be several similar filters on the same page. It would be 'provider' that would change, to something like 'color' or 'size' etc

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it, I implemented a solution that has a much simpler API (wish of Leads in comments). Here it goes:

Add the `cbFilter` dependency to the controller, remove all the `checkbox`-related code and replace it as follows; this is the new API (it can't get any simpler :)

```
app.controller('resultsData', function($scope, $http, cbFilter){
    ...
    $scope.checkbox = cbFilter($scope, "provider.providerId");
    ...
}
```

Rreplace the filter in the list (notice `searchByCheckbox` is replaced by `checkbox`):

```
<li data-ng-repeat="result in ( filteredItems = (results | filter: searchByCarClass | filter: selectCarClass | filter: checkbox )) | orderBy:orderByFilter">
```

And, finally, add the service:

```
app.factory("cbFilter", ["$parse", function($parse) {
    return function($scope, matchExpression) {
        var showAll = true,
            getter = $parse(matchExpression),
            filter = function(data) {
                if( showAll ) return true;
                return filter[getter(data)] === true;
            },
            unwatch = $scope.$watch(
                function() {
                    var x, ret = {};
                    for( x in filter ) {
                        if( !filter.hasOwnProperty(x) ) continue;
                        ret[x] = filter[x];
                    }
                    return ret;
                },
                function() {
                    showAll = true;
                    angular.forEach(filter, function(val) {
                        if( val === true ) showAll = false;
                    });
                },
                true
            );

        $scope.$on("$destroy", unwatch);

        return filter;
    };
}]);
```

The implementation is much more complex than before, and probably slower. However the API is much simpler (one-liner).