# How to filter a collection by the same property twice with checkboxes?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, filter

I'm trying to filter a collection with several checkboxes that use the same property. I can not pass the filter properly. To better explain I send a example [a link](http://plnkr.co/edit/kGdk3Pml9Tt2lWXMW9Ti?p=preview)

Thanks

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764853/angular-checkbox-filtering-data-list

Comment: How about something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/oml5BJBPJn6Y7bocxIFL?p=preview)?