# AngularJS - Filtering by multiple checkbox groups

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for a bit of advice on what's the best way to go about this:

I have about 5 groups of checkboxes. The list would be something like brands, model, colour, size and so on. As a user ticks off a brands, colours etc a list of cars get updated based on their selections.

The list is generated from a call to the database, I know it would be fairly straightforward if the list was generated once as a list that could be filtered entirely on the frontend but the DB is expected to grow to over 10,000 rows so that wouldn't be ideal.

My thinking at first was to post to the DB each time a checkbox is ticked and return the result to the view. This works fine for one set of checkboxes but I can't get my head around how to do it with multiple checkbox groups.

Here's the function in my controller that handles that:

```
$scope.getSelectedBrands = function() {
    $scope.brandsselected = $filter('filter')($scope.brands, {checked: true});  
    var senddata = $filter('filter')($scope.brands, {checked: true});
    $http.post('/brands', senddata).success(function(data, status, response) {
        $scope.cars = data;  
    });        
}
```

I don't know if using a different but very similar function for each checkbox group would make too much sense and doesn't seem very DRY. At the moment each checkbox group e.g brand would have it's own URL to post to to return the set of results. Also since a checkbox in any of the checkbox groups could be ticked first the initial data would be returned from a different function depending on what checkbox was checked.

Is there a better way to approach this? I also would need to allow users to uncheck a checkbox and repopulate the list again.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe my answers to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764853) are relevant to your question - check the 2nd one where things become more reusable.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll have a look. I'm also thinking I could just get the values from the whole form and use that object instead like what the documentation here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I was approaching it the wrong way. All I needed to do was to create a function like the below and fire it whenever a checkbox is checked. It just gets call the form data.

```
$scope.getFormdata = function(){
    var formdata = [{
            brands : $filter('filter')($scope.brands, {checked: true}),
            types : $filter('filter')($scope.types, {checked: true})
    }];
    console.log(formdata);
}
```

Very straightforward.